# Как обойти глюк Eclipse C++?

Tags: c++, eclipse

Работаю в Eclipse C++...

Сделал два проекта. Свою либу и свой некий проект. 
Всё скомпилировал нормально.

Теперь добавил класс в либу. Использую его в своём проекте. Компилиться, получается запускной файл, который работает. Но в самом эклипсе выдаёт, как будто нет такого файла.

Что делать?

P.S. Ошибка «could not be resolved»

Comment: нашёл:

в меню project->c/c++ index/freshen all files

Answer (score 1):

Ответ из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413302/#comment413689_413302):

Нашёл в меню: *project->c/c++ index/freshen all files*.